# Intel HD Graphics violates OpenCL specification regarding SVM?

Tags: pointers, opencl, svm, nvidia, intel

I am trying to allocate several SVM buffers and pass them to an OpenCL kernel using the following method. The kernel is run on Intel HD Graphics 530 and NVIDIA GTX 950M. I get different results on these GPUs, and I am not sure which behavior is correct (maybe, both?)

0. Initialize OpenCL.
1. Allocate 3 buffers (`data0`, `data1`, `pointers`) with 3 clSVMAlloc() calls.
2. Check the results for NULL (no failure here).
3. Map all the buffers using blocking clEnqueueSVMMap() calls + check for CL_SUCCESS (no failure here).
4. Fill `data0` and `data1` with data, and `pointers` with pointers to `data0` and `data1`, so that `pointers[0] == data0` and `pointers[1] == data1`.
5. Unmap all the buffers using clEnqueueSVMUnmap() + check for CL_SUCCESS (no failure here).
6. Set the 1st kernel argument using clSetKernelArgSVMPointer(..., `data0`) + check for CL_SUCCESS (no failure here).
7. Set the 2nd kernel argument using clSetKernelArgSVMPointer(..., `pointers`) + check for CL_SUCCESS (no failure here).
8. Run the kernel and test results.

On NVIDIA card, the data is available through both `pointers[0]` and `pointers[1]`. This is the expected behavior.

On Intel chip, memory behind `pointers[0]` is available (because `data0` has been set as kernel argument), but memory behind `pointers[1]` is all zeroes. If I set `data1` as kernel argument, then it becomes available through `pointers[1]` and memory behind `pointers[0]` becomes zeroes.

The question is: is Intel approach a bug or a feature? I have not found any related information in the OpenCL 3.0 specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel works correctly and adheres to the specification. NVIDIA is more fool-proof, however.

To fix the problem in question, one needs to not forget to pass an array of SVM buffers to a kernel:

```
ret = clSetKernelExecInfo(kernel, CL_KERNEL_EXEC_INFO_SVM_PTRS, sizeof(svm_buffers), svm_buffers);
```

where `svm_buffers` is `void*[]` array of pointers to buffers allocated using clSVMAlloc() calls.

The OpenCL specification states the following for `clSetKernelExecInfo` with parameter `CL_KERNEL_EXEC_INFO_SVM_PTRS`:

> SVM pointers must reference locations
> contained entirely within buffers that are
> passed to kernel as arguments, or that are
> passed through the execution information.
> **Non-argument SVM buffers must be specified by
> passing pointers to those buffers via
> clSetKernelExecInfo** for coarse-grain and fine-
> grain buffer SVM allocations but not for
> finegrain system SVM allocations.